# I need help doing a Regex.Replace with multiple results

Tags: asp.net, regex, donut-caching

I'm building a custom page caching utility that uses a syntax like `{Substitution:GetNonCachedData}` to get data that's not supposed to be cached. The solution is very similar to the built-in `<@ OutputCache %>` stuff but not as flexible (I don't need it to be) and, most importantly, allows the session state to be available when retrieving non-cached data.

Anyway, I have a method that replaces the tokens in the html with the result of the static method named in the {Substitution} tag.

For example my page:

```
<html>
    <body>
      <p>This is cached</p>
      <p>This is not: {Substitution:GetCurrentTime}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

will fill in the `{Substitution:GetCurrentTime}` with results of a static method. Here's where the processing happens:

```
private static Regex SubstitutionRegex = new Regex(@"{substitution:(?<method>\w+)}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

public static string WriteTemplates(string template)
{
    foreach (Match match in SubstitutionRegex.Matches(template))
    {
        var group = match.Groups["method"];
        var method = group.Value;
        var substitution = (string) typeof (Substitution).GetMethod(method).Invoke(null, null);
        template = SubstitutionRegex.Replace()
    }

    return template;

}
```

the variable `template` is the html with custom tokens in it that need to be replaced. The problem with this method is that everytime I update the `template` variable with the updated html the `match.Index` variable no longer points to the right character start because of the `template` now has more characters added to it.

I can come up with a solution that works by either counting characters etc or some other screwball way of doing it, but I first want to make sure there's not some easier way to achieve this with the Regex object. Anyone know how to this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the overload of `Regex.Replace` that takes a `MatchEvaluator` delegate.

For example:

```
return SubstitutionRegex.Replace(template, delegate(Match match) {
    var group = match.Groups["method"];
    var method = group.Value;
    return (string) typeof (Substitution).GetMethod(method).Invoke(null, null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Matches and looping on the results, set the regex to compiled and use a single Match in a while loop until it stops matching.